# Query Cosmos DB for the same objects from multiple schemas

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Give the following documents stored in Cosmos DB, how do I go about getting all of the Child/Children elements where the FirstName field of each child is "Bob"? I'm trying to use the SQL query syntax, but have not found the right way to do this that combines both document schema results.

```
// Document 1
{
    "id": "document1",
    "Child": {
        "FirstName": "Bob",
        "LastName": "Smith"
    }
}

// Document 2
{
    "id": "document2",
    "Children": [
        {
            "Name": "Bob",
            "LastName": "Jones"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Sue",
            "LastName": "Jones"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to write a query that looks for all "Bob" child elements to achieve the following output:

```
[
    {
        "FirstName": "Bob",
        "LastName": "Smith"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Bob",
        "LastName": "Jones"
    },
]
```

Comment: so you have two different names child and children?

Comment: It's more that some documents have a single "Child" element and other documents have that element in an array. In this case the "Child" refers to the common structure rather than the field name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cosmos db documents are stored as json format, you can't treat the Child property(Superior structure) and Children property(Sub structure) equally with a single sql query.

Then can't be flatten and put into one object,please see the example:

[image]

The `c.Child` does not display. So,i'm afraid you need to query `Child` and `Children` separately, then merge them for your requirements.

---

I tried to explain here. In one single query sql is not possible. For example, document 1 does not includes Children Array,document 2 does. In one single sql, `C JOIN Children` is necessary. But for document 1, **Child join nothing is nothing** so that no results will be pulled out. You could try it.

Since UNION feature is not supported by cosmos db, i still suggest following above suggestion to query them separately and merge.

Comment: I wonder if I could use coalesce to try and pull out the Child element when the Children element doesn't exist?

Comment: No, I didn't find a better way unfortunately.